# Upload files from specific repository in Artifactory to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, automation, artifactory

I want to upload files from a single repository (not the whole Artifactory) in Artifactory to Amazon's S3 the moment the file is uploaded to Artifactory. Is there a way to do it?

I'm using a SAAS Artifactory installation, version 7.27.9

Answer (score 2):

At least one of the ways it can be done is using webhooks. You can create a webhook and configure it to notify a service you maintain when an artifact is uploaded (deployed) to the specific repository in Artifactory. Your service will receive an HTTP `POST` request each time a matching artifact is uploaded.

For more details, see `Event: deployed` in the [Webhooks](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Webhooks#Webhooks-Domain:Artifact) documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to have jfrog send it and not have my service download this file? the file could be huge and could take my service hours to download.

Comment: You can try to use JFrog Pipelines for that, using an IncomingWebhook resource. See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/IncomingWebhook

Comment: I don't think this helps me... how can the webhook post a file?

I thought about a different direction - Is there a way to upload a whole artifactory to S3? not a single repository. With an emphasis on the artifactory being SaaS and not On-Prem so I can't edit any XMLs like here
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/S3+Object+Storage

Comment: I'm not sure you can configure your object storage in SaaS, and if you can it probably requires an advanced subscription plan. 
See this experiment I did to validate my proposal: https://github.com/yinonavraham/jfrog-pipelines-experiments/tree/main/on-artifact-deployed
The idea is that the event triggers a pipeline run in which you can get the details of the uploaded file (from the event's payload) and then upload it to your own S3 bucket.

Comment: @yinon first of all thank you for your example. I am trying to use it to send jFrog SaaS logs which is located in artifactory repository "jfrog-logs" to S3 bucket, but seems I can't use "Artifact was deployed" webhook event for this dedicated repository. I don't see it in the list of available repositories in the event configuration. 
Seems like it is the only way to achieve my goal is to use REAS API from outside to get those logs.

Comment: The jfrog-logs is a system internal repository, this is probably why it is not listed in the UI when you try to define the webhook. But you should be able to configure it via REST API - see: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateaNewWebhookSubscription